# How to prevent DOM replacement in angular2 ngFor async in angularfire2?

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I have an async list of messages in an angular2 app using angularfire2.

```
<message *ngFor="let message of messages | async" [message]="message"></message>
```

When the list updates all elements in the ngFor seem to re-render. Is it possible to just re-render the new items in the list?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The re-rendering happens because you changed the actual reference of an object when data retrieves, that time angular `ngFor` re draw all the DOM nodes. For such cases you could use `trackBy` here by which you can make your `*ngFor` smarter.

`trackBy` should be based on unique identity column, in your case I could say it would be `message.id`

```
<message *ngFor="let message of messages | async;trackBy:trackByFn" [message]="message"></message>
```

**Code**

```
trackByFn(message: any){
   // return message != null ? message.id: null;
   // OR
   return message && message.id; //more better
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `trackBy:trackByFn` instead of `trackBy= trackByFn`?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Thanks for heads up, that was missed by me :)

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer yes. fixed.

Comment: thanks. that didn't exactly work, but <message *ngFor="let message of messages | async;trackBy=trackByFn" [message]="message"></message> where trackByFn returns the id did.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I think techically it would have better to have `trackBy=someFn` like `let i = index`(expression) uses `=`

Comment: @okhobb which version you are using?

Comment: "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.5"

Comment: @okhobb it should work with `tackBy:tackByFn`, see [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZVlHCybl43Wff0crirG6?p=preview)

Comment: i think the first argument is index. if you want to use your own id, you need the second argument.
  
    trackByFn(index, item) {
      return (item) ? item.id : undefined;
    }

Comment: @okhobb my whole point to create a plunkr to just show that it does work with whatever contains in updated answer `trackBy: trackByFn` and not `trackBy=trackByFn`

Comment: trackBy didn't fix this for me, I had to remove the async pipe and subscribe to the data: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49547483/3806701

Answer (score 2):

this is the best solution I have seen.

from @[jeffbcros](https://github.com/jeffbcross)

https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/540#issuecomment-248780730

```
class MyComponent {
  trackFbObjects = (idx, obj) => obj.$key;
}

<message *ngFor="let message of messages | async; trackby: trackFbObjects " [message]="message"></message>
```